# About Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

From what I read, $BCH$ formula states that, when $X,Y\in\mathfrak g$ are small enough, then we have $\exp(X)\exp(Y)=\exp(Z)$ where

$$Z=(X+Y)+\frac{1}{2}[X,Y]+\frac{1}{12}\left([X,[X,Y]]-[Y,[X,Y]]\right)+\cdots$$

My question is: Suppose $\exp(X)\exp(Y)=\exp(Z)$ for some $X,Y,Z$ with no requirement on how small $X,Y$ are. Does the $BCH$ formula still hold?

Comment: For what it's worth, the Wikipedia article states [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#cite_ref-15), with a reference [15] to [this text](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~kirillov/mat552/liegroups.pdf), that the Dynkin formula for $\log(\exp(X)\exp(Y))$ is not convergent in general. I'm not sure to what degree the details are addressed in that reference when taking your question at face value, with all $X,Y,Z$ granted to exist (and not just $\exp(X)\exp(Y)$, where the log might not exist) and then only asking about the series convergence.

Comment: @Nikolaj-K Thank you! I took a quick look at the reference you mentioned. The $BCH$ formula is introduced in section 3.7. The statement is the same as what I read elsewhere - assuming $X,Y$ small enough.

Comment: The Wikipedia article has counter-examples to the existence of a $Z$ in the algebra [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Questions_of_convergence). But I suppose your question is a bit more particular, asking if granted $X,Y,Z$ could fail to be related by the formula. Maybe it can be broken by abusing periodicity in $\exp$.

Comment: I found a relevant post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3708505/validity-of-the-baker-campbell-hausdorff-formula-when-convergent?rq=1). The question in the post is that, if the series on the RHS of the $BCH$ formula converges, is it guaranteed $\exp(X)\exp(Y)=\exp(Z)$ where $Z=(X+Y)+\frac{1}{2}[X,Y]+\dots$? I guess mine is kind of the reverse question of his.

Comment: Does the example $$X=Y=\mathbf{0}\qquad\text{and}\qquad Z=2\pi\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ count as a counter-example to your question?

Comment: @SangchulLee Interesting! Yeah I think it does! It's very clever to use the periodicity of $e^z$ in complex numbers. Thank you!